# MVC Model and Controller for Uploaded files

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

My fellow community, I want to ensure that I develop this correctly.  I am working on an ASP.NET MVC 5 application, and while developing the application I am also really studying the architecture of MVC as well to ensure that I really grasp the architecture of MVC.

I currently have a view (see below) that will allow for multiple files to be uploaded on a click of a submit button.

```
<h2>Upload Multiple documents</h2>
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
        {
            <label>Logo File: </label>
            @(Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.File, new { type = "file", Id = "LogoFile" }))
            <label>Privacy PDF: </label>
            @(Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.File, new { type = "file", Id = "PrivacyFile" }))
            <label>Payment Terms PDF: </label>
            @(Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.File, new { type = "file", Id = "PaymentTerms" }))
            <label>Faq File: </label>
            @(Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.File, new { type = "file", Id = "FaqFile" }))

            <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
        }
```

Hence this will call the controller (Note I need to add the foreach loop to handle the multiple files), more on that below -

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Upload(UploadFileModel fileModel)
        {
            const string path = @"C:\_Temp\";
            
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var result = Path.GetFileName(fileModel.File.FileName);
                if (result != null)
                {

                    var sections = result.Split('\\');
                    var fileName = sections[sections.Length - 1];

                    fileModel.File.SaveAs(path + fileName);
                }
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

Which then calls the model -

```
public class UploadFileModel //: IEnumerable
    {
        [FileSize(10240)]
        [FileTypes("jpg,jpeg,png,pdf")]
        public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }

        //NEWLY ADDED AFTER COMMENTS - would I add it here?????????
         public IEnumerable<UploadFileModel> UploadFileModels { get; set; }
    }
```

My thought is that the controller code should be moved to the model from what I am reading online and in books.

Question 1 - Should the code in the controller be moved to the Model?  Because from what I am researching the business logic should be handled in the model.

Question 2 - Since this will be a collection (I am not strong on collections, but am striving to be a master).
    a) Do I add another class for the collection called UploadFileModels which is strictly for the collection or do I simply build out the UploadFileModel to inherent and handle collections and if so how?

Thank you.

Comment: Moving logic into model is good practice . you dont need to add any other class to handle collection.

Comment: How would I code for the collection any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Question 1:  I would say the code should be moved into the model.  The purpose for this is actually two fold.  1 it makes the code easier to understand and read if the business logic is separated from the controller.  2. It makes testing much easier if you decouple the business logic from the controller logic, so yes i would definitely recommend moving your logic into a function on the model.

Question 2: Do not add a class for the collection.  To add a collection to your post your method signature should be something like:

```
public ActionResult Upload(IEnumerable<UploadFileModel> fileModel)
```

and your model class should be:

```
public class UploadFileModel //: IEnumerable
{
    [FileSize(10240)]
    [FileTypes("jpg,jpeg,png,pdf")]
    public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }
}
```

and your controller now takes a collection.  As a side note as your model class stands right now you really don't need it at all, you could simply use

```
public ActionResult Upload(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> fileModel)
```

and do your buisness logic in a controller repository model.  I would not recommend doing this, because if you want to make changes your controller it makes it much more difficult, but it is worth noteing

Answer (score 0):

Try this method

```
public class UploadFileModel //: IEnumerable
    {
        [FileSize(10240)]
        [FileTypes("jpg,jpeg,png,pdf")]
        public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }

        public void Save() { 

        //Put your Saving Logic
        }

    }

    // An Extension method for operating files

    public static class Extensions{
        public static void PerformSave (this IEnumerable<UploadFileModel> collection){


            foreach (var item in collection)
            {
                item.Save();
            }

     }

   }
```

Change your controller to

```
public ActionResult Upload(IEnumerable<UploadFileModel> fileModels){

if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
  fileModels.PerformSave();
}
return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: you can put your saving logic in extension method or uploadfilemodel